# Why is the pip installation of Cython taking so long?

Tags: python, numpy, pip

Few minutes ago I tried to install Cython on my computer (currently I'm working on Windows 10, Python 3.6), and I typed "pip install Cython" to command prompt, so it has downloaded it successfully, now installation still lasts, it has been working about 10 minutes, so something is wrong. The same story happened with NumPy, but I've given up with installation, because it isn't necessary for me now. Any ideas? Before I've updated Visual C++, because when I tried to install NumPy, error occurred and referred me to install last Visual C++ version so I did it with link attached with error message.
[image: Screenshot from console]

Comment: probably it is compiling, you should either wait, or give more details on what is happening in the console.

Comment: https://scr.hu/6AlB22

Comment: @dannyxn you should edit your question and directly embed it (don't link externally)

Comment: Both need to compile a lot of things. In case of you are having a slow computer it will take even longer. Check your task manager to see what its doing. But most likely you will see compiler process running and consuming a lot of resources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's taking a long time because it's compiling the library from it's C source. Depending on the speed of your computer and the size of the library, this can take a long time.

You say you're not seeing any output while the compilation takes place. Most likely the setup that starts the compiling isn't piping `stdout` and `stderr` lines. Have a look at your Task Manager and see if the compiler process is taking up a lot of CPU, if it is, then most likely it's working. Leave the machine alone while it compiles (don't watch videos in the background, etc.), plug it in if it's a laptop.

There may be pre-compiled binaries in the wild, but they'll need to be linked against the same version of Python you're using.

Comment: But as I remember, when I was installing, for example NumPy, on my old computer, there wasn't the same problem, now I'm working on much faster.

Comment: Why doesn't the he see the output of the compilation then? At least on Linux, installing Cython produces loads of output.

Comment: I was asking about that

Comment: Becouse i felt that something is wrong, I am worrying about no output in console

Comment: You should mention in your question that you're not seeing any output.

Comment: I pasted screenshot

Comment: Installing cython on a raspberry pi 3 with python 3.6.3 took ~15 minutes just now, and appeared to hang at the same point as in @dannyxn's screenshot for most of that time, before completing successfully.  Just give it time.